# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\right)\frac{dx}{x\left(3x^2 - 3x +1\right)}$

Tags: integration

I have it on good authority that the following monstrosity

$$I=\int_0^1 \sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}\right)\frac{dx}{x\left(3x^2 - 3x +1\right)}$$

is not only convergent but has an analytic closed form. After spending a long time struggling with it I was not able to convert it into a familiar form, mainly because of the nested function within the $\sin(\cdot)$ term which I am unable to get rid of.

The essential singularities of the integrand about $x=0$ and $x=1$ make it difficult even to approximate the integral to any meaningful precision, so I am unable even to formulate a conjecture as to the closed form.

I am hoping that some kind soul will be able to rid me of this suspense and solve the devil-incarnate that is this integral.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}$ is symmetric with respect to $x=\frac{1}{2}$. No devil here.

Comment: Probably, King's rule of integration may help $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(a+b-x)dx$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin\left(\frac{1-2x}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}\right)\frac{dx}{x(3x^2-3x+1)}\stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1+z}{2}}{=}-4\int_{-1}^{1}\sin\left(\frac{2z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right)\frac{dz}{(1+z)(1+3z^2)}$$
Through the substitution $z=\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}$ the last integral becomes

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\sin(t)\frac{t-\sqrt{4+t^2}}{1+t^2}\,dt =\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{t\sin(t)}{1+t^2}\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{e}}$$
due to parity and the residue theorem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how your note about the symmetry of the $\sin(\cdots)$ part of the integral led you to this solution?

Comment: @Chris: such symmetry leads to the RHS of the first line that is way more promising than the starting point. After that it is enough to perform a change of variable, in order to turn $\frac{2z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$ into $t$, to brilliantly solve the mistery.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm quite amazed by the efficiency of your solution. What you did in three substitutions would have taken me ten. Nice work.