# How do we find closed form of $\int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{x^n\over 1-x^m}}\mathrm dx=F(n,m)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Consider this integral

Motivated by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237207/evaluate-int-01-sin-left-sqrt-frac1-xx-sqrt-fracx1-x-right-fr)

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{x^n\over 1-x^m}}\mathrm dx=F(n,m)\tag1$$
>   Where $n\ge -1$ and $m\ge 1$

We note the following values for $F(n,m):$

$$F(-1,1)=\pi$$

$$F(1,1)={\pi\over 2}$$

$$F(1,3)={\pi\over 3}$$

**Where $k $ is an integer, what are other values of $ n$ and $m$ that will give ${\pi\over k}$?**

I guess to answer this question we have to find the closed form for $(1)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**. This is the [Euler beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in disguise, by the change of variable 
$$u=x^m, \quad x=u^{1/m}, \quad dx=\frac1m\cdot u^{1/m-1}du,
$$ one gets, for $n\ge-1,\, m>0,$

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{x^n\over 1-x^m}}\:\mathrm dx&=\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)^{-\large\frac12}u^{\large\frac{n+2}{2m}-1}\:du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\:\Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2m}\right)}{m\: \Gamma \left(\frac{m+n+2}{2 m}\right)},\quad 
> \end{align}
> $$

then by properties of the gamma function one may simplify the preceding expression.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* says:

$$
\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{m+2}{2
   n}\right)}{n \Gamma \left(\frac{m+n+2}{2 n}\right)},\Re(n)>0\land \Re(m)>-2\right]
$$